# td.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to append a child to a td element. here is the HTML I am working with,

```
<td colspan="8" class="sectionExpandColumn courseResultLL courseResultLR">
    <a class="sectionExpand collapsibleCriteria" action=sectionDetail">
        sections
    </a>
  </td>
```

I want it to be,

```
<td colspan="8" class="sectionExpandColumn courseResultLL courseResultLR">
    <a class="sectionExpand collapsibleCriteria" action=sectionDetail">
        sections
    </a>
    <a class="sectionExpand collapsibleCriteria" action=sectionDetail">
        discussion
    </a>
  </td>
```

just simply addding a link tag under td, really.

so in my script,

```
div = table.getElementsByClassName("sectionExpandColumn");
var button = document.createElement("a");
button.setAttribute("class", "sectionExpand.collapsibleCriteria");
button.innerHTML = "Discussion";
div.appendChild(button);
```

I am getting Uncaught TypeError: div.appendChild is not a function
Why is it?

## Update

Thank you for telling me that I'm working with a htmlcollection!

So I added this code,

```
for (var i=0; i<div.length; i++){
    div[i].appendChild(button);
  }
```

But it runs through just fine, but at the end, it only adds the element to the last div. I'm trying to make a sense out of this... Could you tell me why?

Comment: Because `div` is not td, it's HTMLCollection: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: **div** is an *array like object* of elements, not an element.

Comment: Did you want the element to be appended to every td with class of sectionExpandColumn or just one in particular?

Comment: I want the be appended to every td. I updated my question. Could you please look at it?

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, your variable **div** is not an *element*, but an *array like object*.  You can try:

```
div = table.getElementsByClassName("sectionExpandColumn");
var button = document.createElement("a");
button.setAttribute("class", "sectionExpand.collapsibleCriteria");
button.innerHTML = "Discussion";

div[0].appendChild(button);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code:

```
<td colspan="8" class="sectionExpandColumn courseResultLL courseResultLR">
        <a class="sectionExpand collapsibleCriteria" action="sectionDetail">
            sections
        </a>

      </td>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.sectionExpandColumn').append('<a class="sectionExpand collapsibleCriteria" action=sectionDetail"> discussion</a>');
```

Comment: You are referencing it as a id not a class. Making it $('.sectionExpandColumn')

Comment: @JonSG to be fair OP did mark this under Jquery category.

Comment: @mattfetz, good call... I am removing that note.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
    var div = document.getElementsByClassName("sectionExpandColumn");
    var button = document.createElement("a");
    button.setAttribute("class", "sectionExpand.collapsibleCriteria");
    button.innerHTML = "Discussion";
    div.innerHTML +=button;
```